# Binary subtraction using an algorithm to determine what XOR and XNOR coefficient gates to use.

Tags: logic, solution-verification, algorithms, propositional-calculus, binary

Let $n \ge 0$ and $(a_i)_{\,0 \le i \le n}$, $(b_i)_{\,0 \le i \le n}$ be given where, for all $i$, $a_i, b_i \in \{0,1\}$.

Let

$\quad \displaystyle {a = \sum_{0 \le i \le n} a_i 2^i}$

and

$\quad \displaystyle {b = \sum_{0 \le i \le n} b_i 2^i}$

and assume that $b \lt a$ so that if $c = a - b$ we can write

$\quad \displaystyle {c = \sum_{0 \le i \le n} c_i 2^i \quad \text{where } c_i \in \{0,1\} }$

Recall the $\text{XOR }$ (numeric) truth tables,

$$\begin{array}{cc|c}
p & q & p \nleftrightarrow q  \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$

and its negation,

$$\begin{array}{cc|c}
p & q & p \leftrightarrow q  \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$

Claim: There is a symbolic processing algorithm that takes the inputs $(a_i)_{\,0 \le i \le n}$ and $(b_i)_{\,0 \le i \le n}$ and constructs a function

$\quad \mu: \{0,1,\dots,n\} \to \{\nleftrightarrow,\leftrightarrow\}$

such that for each $0 \le i \le n$, $\;c_i = a_i \, \mu(i) \, b_i$.

I tried proving this by (strong) induction, but I get off course and wind up just pointing to the simple algorithmic highlights of this subtraction technique.

> Please supply a proof of my claim, and if convenient use your own
> formulation/notation to express the above thinking.

**My work**

As I worked on concrete subtraction problems I realized that before calculating any numbers I could figure out all the logic gates to use for each $a_i$ | $b_i$ pair.

I also observed that if whenever $a_i =0$ it had to be the case that $b_i = 0$, then there would be no $\leftrightarrow$ processing gates.

Example 1: To calculate $11000_2 - 1011_2$ one writes out in a completely mechanical fashion (by examining the two expressions digit by digit from right to left)

$$
\begin{array}{c}
&1&1&0&0&0\\
&0&1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\\hline
&\leftrightarrow&\leftrightarrow&\leftrightarrow&\leftrightarrow&\nleftrightarrow
\end{array}
$$

and then by applying the digit by digit boolean calculations,

$$
\begin{array}{c}
&1&1&0&0&0\\
&0&1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\\hline
&\leftrightarrow&\leftrightarrow&\leftrightarrow&\leftrightarrow&\nleftrightarrow\\\hline
&0&1 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
$$

we know that $11000_2 - 1011_2 = 1101_2$.

Example 2: To calculate $110111000101_2 - 101101011100_2$, we put up our two string work area,

$$
\begin{array}{c}
&1&1&0&1&1&1&0&0&0&1&0&1\\
&1&0&1&1&0&1&0&1&1&1&0&0
\end{array}
$$

and inspect it from right to left looking looking for the first $0$ over $1$. We find it and paint the corresponding segment (up to the first $1$ over $0$ occurrence) after it red,

$$
\begin{array}{c}
&1&1&0&1&\color{red}1&\color{red}1&\color{red}0&\color{red}0&0&1&0&1\\
&1&0&1&1&\color{red}0&\color{red}1&\color{red}0&\color{red}1&1&1&0&0
\end{array}
$$

Repeating we see one final segment,

$$
\begin{array}{c}
&1&\color{red}1&0&1&\color{red}1&\color{red}1&\color{red}0&\color{red}0&0&1&0&1\\
&1&\color{red}0&1&1&\color{red}0&\color{red}1&\color{red}0&\color{red}1&1&1&0&0
\end{array}
$$

and then by applying the digit by digit boolean calculations,

$$
\begin{array}{c}
&1&\color{red}1&0&1&\color{red}1&\color{red}1&\color{red}0&\color{red}0&0&1&0&1\\
&1&\color{red}0&1&1&\color{red}0&\color{red}1&\color{red}0&\color{red}1&1&1&0&0\\\hline
&\nleftrightarrow&\leftrightarrow&\nleftrightarrow&\nleftrightarrow&\leftrightarrow&\leftrightarrow&\leftrightarrow&\leftrightarrow&\nleftrightarrow&\nleftrightarrow&\nleftrightarrow&\nleftrightarrow\\\hline
& 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
$$

we know that $110111000101_2 - 101101011100_2 = 1001101001_2$.